# Display flickering and going black on 15.04 - Lenovo Y40-70

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, display, monitor

**The Problem:**

The problem began a few weeks ago when my display started to flicker on the login screen. Recently the flickering became much worse, especially when browsing the web. Any update to the image on the display causes flickering. When it's at it's worst, even typing causes it to flicker and the screen will go completely black.

**What I've tried:**

I have two graphics cards installed, but switching between them (using AMD Catalyst Control Center) does not help. The problem also persists when booting into my Windows 8 partition. Restarting the computer sometimes helps temporarily. The display does not seem to be affected at all by jiggling or tapping. I stripped a screw trying to open the computer up, so I haven't been able to check for loose connections or other damage yet.

**The Cards:**

Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller

AMD Radeon R9 M275X

**UPDATE 1**

My computer is a Lenovo Y40-70 Laptop.

Also had Ubuntu 12.04 installed, which was listed as a problem in some similar questions I found. Removing Ubuntu 12.04 had no effect.

I now think that this is a hardware issue with the screen itself. When I turn the display back-light completely off and shine a light at the screen I can see that the pixels are still being rendered and there is no flicker.

Comment: Possibly a bad monitor? Try connecting another monitor or connecting your current monitor to another device?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you may want to check is pushing the settings buttons on the side. If the menus are problematic as well, your screen is likely going out. If you have a spare screen or device, you will want to go with process of elimination. But if you don't, that my be something that you can try.

If it persists / is associated with the computer, then maybe it is a motherboard issue?

As for the stripped screw, you can try using a nail and tapping it lightly at an angle to move the screw out (unscrew) very slowly. The other option is to take an old bit and superglue ( or JB Weld) it to the screw and **carefully** remove it.

Good Luck,
Joey

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a lenovo laptop.  Screen flickers, goes black.  There is a video on youtube demonstrating a fix.  Basically, remove the keyboard and top and underneath is a video chip dongle which, when removed and put back, fixes the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have Windows also on your computer.  May have opened up a stronger possibility of getting a computer virus that is causing this issue.  I would try running a virus software like COMODO antivirus.  I am not saying that this is the only answer or solution.  Just that this is a strong possibility.